# Python Terminated Thread Cannot Restart

Tags: python, multithreading, runtime-error

I have a thread that gets executed when some action occurs. Given the logic of the program, the thread cannot possibly be started while another instance of it is still running. Yet when I call it a second time, I get a "RuntimeError: thread already started" error. I added a check to see if it is actually alive using the Thread.is_alive() function, and it is actually dead.

What am I doing wrong?

I can provide more details as are needed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Threads cannot be restarted. You must re-create the Thread in order to start it again.

Answer (score 7):

From the [Python](http://docs.python.org/lib/thread-objects.html) documentation:
`start()`
starts the thread's activity.
This must be called at most once per thread object. It arranges for the object's `run()`method to be invoked in a separate thread of control.

If you derive a class from threading.Thread you can add a `Thread.__init__(self)` at the end of your run method and you'll be able to call start again and it'll automatically reinitialize itself when done.

Answer (score 2):

You can try setting

```
thread._Thread__started = False
```

It isn't officially documented, so use it on your own risk! :)

Comment: I am already using _Thread__stop() to start it... Adding one does not seem to so bad, but makes my program really hacky...